# Applications of Chameleon Particles: Space Constructs

Tags: science-based, space, space-constructs

**Dark Energy** is a very strange force, and one of the theorised carriers of this force is the **Chameleon Particle**. To describe its effects, due to its non-linear self-interaction, it has a variable level of interaction. In places where the density of matter is relatively high, chameleon particles are **heavier**, interact **very weakly** with other matter and only over **very short distances** (*in the range of less than 1mm*).

However, in inter-galactic space where matter density is extremely low, the particles are **lighter**, interact **much more strongly** with other matter and over **very large distances** (*over 100,000+ parsecs*). This means that the particles could be exerting a force that is pushing the universe apart.

Assuming we could mass produce this particle, given that this theory is *correct* for our world, how could this be used for space constructs (*such as for space habitats and propulsion*)? It will likely be useless on land, so ideas will likely be more regarding air and outer space.

Note: *This is a more clear version of the previous question, by behest of the mods of this wiki. I will probably ask about other applications in another thread.*

Comment: When saying "interact", what do you mean, pulling, pushing? And can you give a rough estimate of distances and forces? Very short distance like in atom interactions? 10cm? 1m? If we have particles the size of a soccer ball, force would be like a car, a spaceship's thrust, a whole planet gravity? Could really help to answer

Comment: Small error: Heavier and lighter are meant to be swapped. Also, in response to the above, I mean a push. Short distances mean like less than 1mm. Long distances mean like 100,000+ parsecs.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with worldbuilding resources. Therefore the tag has been removed. Please pick other relevant tags, as science based is not self sufficient

Comment: (a) I love the premise of the Chameleon Particle. (b) Why wouldn't the theory be correct? It's your world. (c) On the other hand, asking for potential uses is, to me, an off-topic request for an [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) rather than an on-topic request for a [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609). Raw idea generation is a bad fit for Stack Exchange (we're expected to abide by their rules). Can you explain how you would choose a best answer? Otherwise, VTC:OB.

Comment: I made some edits. Would this work?

Comment: Someone reopen this.